# Regex get the attribute value following another attribute

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to get the value of an attribute, given the preceding text. Say I have this:

```
<meta content="firsttag" name="datatoget" />
```

I want to get the `value` of name (datatoget).
 I know what's before the specific attribute (`<meta ... name="`)

How can I, using regular expressions, get this value?

I got `content="firstag" name=".*"`, which will return what I wanted, but with the surrounding text. Basically I want the `.* part.

Comment: Obligatory: [Have you tried using an HTML parser instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/953482) I'm sure many parsing libraries have lovely `getAttribute` methods which would work quite well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454,
are you pulling a whole html page? or just have this 1 string? if you have a full html document please look at a html parser, lxml, beautiful soup,

Comment: No, i'm not parsing complete documents, it's some text identical every time, and I only need one simple value so I figured using regex would be better.

Comment: You are on the right track just use `()` to capture the value you want `content="firsttag" name="(.*?)"`

Comment: Regex is probably fine in that case. As much as SO loves to link the answer that dm and I linked, you _can_ parse a string with regex if it's a small subset of HTML with no nested tags and other such Zalgo-summoning properties that have tripped up so many devs.

Comment: Kevin, I'll promise to leave Cthulu alone ;) 
@RanRag That sorta worked, only it matches 2 things now: The part I want, but also the whole part (content... ")

Comment: @ceeee: I tried it with the string you mentioned above and it only outputs `[datatoget]`.

Comment: I have it working now. It worked indeed RanRag, I was testing it in some browser regex tester, and it turned out it was kinda bugged. In python it worked great! Thanks, maybe you can make an Answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=name=")[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

`(?<=name=")` makes sure that the text 'name="' is behind what we want to match without including it in your result.

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` limits the capture group so that the end quote isn't included in it.